# Can I fly RNAV 5 with only INS?

Tags: military, inertial-nav-system, rnav, c-130

First of all, I'm not a native English speaker, and this is my first question, so please understand that it can be very awkward.

My military C-130H aircraft has DME/VOR, TACAN, ILS, and INS (EGI, LN-100R). (These are navigation equipment from the 1980s.). There are no GPS, no FMS.

My question is, can this aircraft use Y Airway?

Since I usually fly VFR in local area, I have little knowledge about RNAV.
As far as I understand, RNAV 5 is an En Route phase, and requires equipment that can use ground stations(like VOR) and INS or GNSS equipment.
Since my aircraft has VOR/DME and INS, is it capable of RNAV 5? If so, can I use Y Airway?
If not, is a separate certification or authentication required to use RNAV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to fly RNAV-5, the aircraft equipment needs to be approved to do so. [This Air Force publication](https://static.e-publishing.af.mil/production/1/af_a3/publication/afman11-2c-130hv3/afman11-2c-130hv3.pdf) indicates that C-130H aircraft are capable of RNAV-5 navigation, subject to some requirements on aligning the inertial navigation system.

Exactly what that will permit you to fly depends on where in the world you are. In the US, all airways are RNAV-2 or stricter, so RNAV-5 is useless. You say in comments that you are in Japan, and it does appear that Japan has some RNAV-5 airways.

It should go without saying that you should clarify this with someone with local knowledge. There may be local regulations or rules I am unaware of.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Then, among the RNAV routes such as Y, T, and Q, are there any routes that I can use?

Comment: @Tom Are you in the US? All RNAV airways in the NAS are RNAV 2 or better, so they are all off limits. Elsewhere in the world the answer may be different.

Comment: No I am in Japan. According to your answer, my aircraft may be capable of RNAV 5. So what does RNAV 5 enable? They said RNAV 5 is the enroute phase, so I thought it meant the RNAV airway.

Comment: @Tom Edited my answer. Some of the information in it before was US-specific.

Comment: Thank you very much