# Does RNAV 5 requires certification in Japan?

Tags: rnav, c-130, japan

Through [the last question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/99241/can-i-fly-rnav-5-with-only-ins), I learned that the C-130H is an aircraft capable of RNAV 5.

Then my colleagues raised another question.

"According to the US Airforce manual, it is true that RNAV 5 is possible, but is it really possible in our country?

(Of course, it is true that the C-130H was imported from the United States)
Is it okay to perform RNAV 5 without some certifications?"

This is a question of regulation or law in Japan.

Does the RNAV5 need to be certified for onboard equipment or for aircraft when operating in Japan?

Comment: Hi Tom, from a comment to an answer to the linked question I gather you are from Japan. I added this info to this question, because that is important information when you want to know about regulation and laws.

Comment: Thank you for your help